# Java change server and database setting for security

Tags: java, properties, configuration, ini

I have a old projects developed by java and that old project made by Jdk 1.4 version.

This is single application java program.

Currently server and database configuration is written by .ini file.

but That is not really good for security because everybody can see this file physically.

Do you guys have any way to hide perfectly instead of using .ini file.

I think this is two way.

```
1. Make properties class in side of project and make .jar files.
- I can make .jar file but also I can decode it.

2. Separate Back-End server and communicate.
- This way I have to fix too many source code. So I am not sure it's good or not.
- Also what is this concept for specific we are calling in Java environment?
```

And anything else please suggest to me

Thank you!

Comment: I am unclear what you are concerned about. Are you afraid having a config file on your server is insecure? That does not really have anything to do with Java, and more to do with the general security of your server.

Comment: There is Settings.ini file And inside of that there is ID=?? , PASSWORD=???  DBPASSWORD=???  DBNAME=??? ..... So it will show every information access to database. So I want to hide for this infomration

Comment: You are not being clear about where this file is currently located. It is not at all unusual to have a web project that has a configuration file that contains database credentials.

Comment: this file located same as main.jar file which run java application program. If I don't need to make this server is there any better way to make secure that file? I was thinking to use JDBC and make a class file to having id and password information in side of project, but it will show if I decode .jar file isn't it?

Comment: You should never place sensitive data in code files because of the same reason you just mentoined. Is it possible for you to simply encrypt the config file? When you start up your application you simply decrypt the data in memory and use it?

Comment: @univise I don't know what you are talking about, configuration information including database user names and passwords are frequently stored as part of a web application. That does not make it insecure. As long as your web server is secure, I am not sure how you think someone would be able to get access to the file.

Comment: @thatidiotguy It may also be that I misinterpreted the askers comment but the asker just suggested placing the data inside the project that will be compiled, right? Decompiling the resulting .jar would expose that data again.

Comment: @univise If you have people that can access your JAR that implies they are on your server and you already have serious problems.

Comment: @thatidiotguy you are right. It is obvious that you have other problems if people can access your server like that. "That is not really good for security because everybody can see this file physically" though implies no less than that. Furthermore, security design should not assume 'That should not happen so I dont need to secure it' - security design should assume 'Even if, we have the data secured'. Why otherwise would sensitive data, like passwords, be encrypted on todays databases servers, just as one example? This is the same reason why I suggested encrypting the config file.

Comment: @univise Thank you for both of us, User can see .jar file this mean this application installed client side, and directly connect to the database server from client pc. As Univise mentioned I will try to encrypt configuration files!

Comment: Your are welcome. Though encryption should be the least protection of your files; you should consider that when you decrypt the files, the passwords will be in memory - which is not optimal. Instead take the encrypted password, send it to your server, let your server decrypt it and the server will check whether the password was correct

Comment: @univise I will select your answer please Answer my question and say about using encryption ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least protection you can provide to your configuration file is encrypting it.

> 1. Make properties class [inside] of project and make .jar files.

As I pointed out in the comments, you should never place sensitive data in compiled files. For one, it makes your design quite unflexible: If you decided to change your server password, for instance, you would also have to change your compiled files. As a second and more important reason, saving configuration data in compiled code is insecure; especially for Java, there are decompilers out there which can be used to decompile and thus retrieve the sensitive data.

> 2. Separate Back-End server and communicate.

I do not understand what is meant by this so I will not comment on it.

A means to secure your files is encrypting them; this is the least layer of protection though. When you login to your server sent the encrypted password to your server and the server, knowing the encryption key, will be able to decrypt the password and check whether the password is valid. While the last part may seem to be obvious, I insist on communicating that to you.

However, you should not rely on encryption solely. Furthermore, if the information you are protecting is not client specific, such as their login credentials, you should not store it on the clients computer in the first place; anything can happen on the clients computer - the client may even be the one trying to crack the your sensitive data. If you do not have to, do not store it on a computer you do not have control over. I do not know you circumstances, so there are hardly specific answers I (and the community) could provide.

I hope this answer helped you